# SignalR dispose of HubConnection

Tags: asp.net, .net, dispose, signalr.client, signalr-2

In a AspNet SignalR client is it the action to dispose of a `HubConnection` necessary?

It seems to take some time, from what I have seen...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not necessary if you are calling `Stop()`.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn235890(v=vs.118).aspx

otherwise, you should always Dispose of `IDisposable` objects when you are done using them.

If it is taking too long (i.e., blocking the current thread), just stop it on a `Task`, something like:

```
Task.Run(()=>hubConnection.Stop());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not calling `stop()`, once it is exactly the same thing as `Dispose()`. From the signalr source code `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Stop();
            }
        }`

Comment: Disposing the connection in a separate task does the trick, but is it a common practice?

Comment: @cangosta, yes, it is common if you do not want the disposing of it to block.

Comment: Its a pain but:
Task.Run(() => this.hubConnection.Dispose()).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by *it takes too much time*? Can you detail? Are you getting timeout exception?

From the book C# 5.0 in a Nutshell:

> A safe rule to follow (in nearly all cases) is “if in doubt, dispose.”
> A disposable object —if it could talk—would say the following:
>
> When you’ve finished with me, let me know. If simply abandoned, I might
> cause trouble for other object instances, the application domain, the
> computer, the network, or the database!

I would say dispose if it's not a dealbreaker. Also might be useful to find out what takes so long time there.

Comment: Actually, it just blocks the running thread and then ends successfully. No exceptions are thrown. I can't figure out why is it taking so much time to dispose.

Comment: it takes 30 seconds to dispose the object

Comment: In fact, 30 seconds is the default timeout for the dispose operation.